# Correct place for lib compiled with special flags for a single program

Tags: deb, packaging, shared-library, lintian

Hello I am trying to create a debian package of a program I wrote bundled with a library. Since I am using special flags to compile the library I only want to provide the library for my program. While I can do so using the `runpath` I am not sure were to put the library.  `lintian` complains about `/opt`, `/lib` or `/usr/lib` is wrong since I do not want to replace the debian packaged version of the librarycompiled with different flags.

I do not want to use static linkage. Where should I put my library file?

Comment: /opt/lib/ is OK. Start your program with `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && [start-command]`

Comment: @KnudLarsen: any way to make `Lintian` not complain about files in `/opt` then? (I am trying to minimize warnings, which would ideally mean get zero warnings)

Comment: Keep the library and the executable in an "app directory/", and use a script in PATH for start : `cd [dir/] ; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && [./start-command]`